# Count number of ways to place integers such that sum of 2x2 sub grid equals to n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-partition

You are given a kxk grid. You can place an integer m (a ≤ m ≤ b) in each cell.
How many ways are there to place integers in the cells such that the sum of each 2x2 subgrid is n ?

For example These are the cases for k=3, a=1, b=2 and n=5.

```
2 1 2
1 1 1
2 1 2
```

or

```
2 1 2
1 1 1
1 2 1
```

or

```
2 1 1
1 1 2
2 1 1
```

or

```
1 2 1
1 1 1
2 1 2
```

or

```
1 2 1
1 1 1
1 2 1
```

or

```
1 1 2 
2 1 1
1 1 2
```

or

```
1 1 1
2 1 2
1 1 1
```

or

```
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 1
```

Hence answer for this case would be 8 ways.

My approach: is to solve the problem in for a linear list of k elements with moving window of size 2. and then for each possible valid pairs find all ordered partitions,

Comment: "You can place an integer m (a ≤ m ≤ b) in each cell"  What are $a$ and $b$? "such that the sum of each 2x2 subgrid is n" What is $n$?  If $n < 4a$ or $n>4b$ then the answer is $0$.  If $n = 4a$ or $4b$ then the answer is $1$.

Comment: @fleablood a,b,k,n are all non-negative integres. to avoid invalid cases you can add constraint of k>=2. So basically n<4a  or n>4b  all cases have to be considered.